# How to goto end of all split files in vim simultaneously?

Tags: vim

How can I goto end of all files opened in vertical or horizontal splits in vim in a go?
i.e, apply GG to all files at the same time opened in split mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as required `:windo $`

Here, `windo` executes a command in each window and `$` is a command-mode argument for going to end of file.